# Python QT - No module named 'ui.mainwindow'

Tags: python, pyqt

i am trying to run my main.py but i always get the same error.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ui.mainwindow'
```

I already tried with other commands like `ui.MainWindow`, `ui.mainWindow`, `Ui.MainWindow` but nothing worked. Can someone help me?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question to show a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your own attempt, together with a description of the problems you have with it.

Comment: add `__init__.py` in `ui`

Comment: @eyllanesc can you explain where and how to add it?

Comment: create an empty file with that name in the ui folder

Comment: @eyllanesc i tried to add just an empty _ _init_ _.py file in folder ui but still the same error

Comment: problem solved. i needed to compile mainwindow.ui to mainwindow.py first and then ask for the import from ui.mainwindow